# Use BeautifulSoup to Replace Every Occurrence of XML Tag with Another Tag

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup

I am trying to replace every occurrence of an XML tag in a document (call it the target) with the contents of a tag in a different document (call it the source). The tag from the source could contain just text, or it could contain more XML.

Here is a simple example of what I am not able to get working:

**test-source.htm**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <srctxt>text to be added</srctxt>
    </body>
</html>
```

**test-target.htm**:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
    <replacethis src="test-source.htm"></replacethis>
    <p>irrelevant, just here for filler</p>
    <replacethis src="test-source.htm"></replacethis>
    </body>
</html>
```

**replace_example.py**:

```
import os
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Just for testing

source_file = "test-source.htm"
target_file = "test-target.htm"

with open(source_file) as s:
    source = BeautifulSoup(s, "lxml")

with open(target_file) as t:
    target = BeautifulSoup(t, "lxml")

source_tag = source.srctxt

for tag in target():
    for attribute in tag.attrs:
        if re.search(source_file, str(tag[attribute])):
            tag.replace_with(source_tag)

with open(target_file, "w") as w:
    w.write(str(target))
```

**This is my unfortunate `test-target.htm` after running `replace_example.py`**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html>
<head>
</head>
<body>

<p>irrelevant, just here for filler</p>
<srctxt>text to be added</srctxt>
</body>
</html>
```

The first `replacethis` tag is now gone and the second `replacethis` tag has been replaced. This same problem happens with "insert" and "insert_before".

The output I want is:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?><html>
<head>
</head>
<body>
<srctxt>text to be added</srctxt>    
<p>irrelevant, just here for filler</p>
<srctxt>text to be added</srctxt>
</body>
</html>
```

Can someone please point me in the right direction?

---

*Additional Complications:* The example above is the simplest case where I could reproduce the problem I seem to be having with BeautifulSoup, but it does not convey the full detail of the problem I'm trying to solve. Actually, I have a list of targets and sources. The `replacethis` tag needs to be replaced by the contents of a source only if the `src` attribute contains a reference to a source in the list. So I could use the replace method, but it would require writing a lot more regex than if I could convince BeautifulSoup to work. If this problem is a BeautifulSoup bug, then maybe I'll just have to write the regex instead.

Comment: Are those XML strings actually different files? And where did `<html><body>` derive?

Comment: The `<html><body>` are part of the object BeautifuSoup creates from the XML strings. AFAIK.

Comment: What is your desired output -an XML file or HTML file? And again, are those targets/sources actual XML files or strings? If so, the *target_text* is not a valid XML string as it does not contain a root, possibly why `<html><body>` is auto-wrapped. I think your example is too simplified. Please provide snippets of actual.

Comment: @Parfait I was using the XML strings as stand-ins for files in a (possibly) misguided attempt to simplify the problem for those trying to help me. I have updated the OP with example files/code.

Answer (score 1):

You could use another parser (`html.parser`) if you want to get rid of extra tags.

BS4's `replace_with` behavior looks like some bug in library.

As a partial solution you can just call

`target_text.replace('<replacethis></replacethis>', source_text)`

Comment: It would be much better if I could use BeautifulSoup instead of `replace`. I added some additional explanation on why that is to the OP. Thanks, though.

Answer (score 1):

First, it is highly advised to not use [regex on [X]HTML documents](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Since you are modifying XML content, consider an `lxml` solution which you do have installed being the parsing engine in your `BeautifulSoup` calls. No `for` or `if` logic needed for this approach.

Specifically, consider [XSLT](https://www.w3.org/Style/XSL/), the special-purpose language, designed to transform XML into other XML, HTML, even json/csv/txt files. XSLT maintains the `document()` function allowing you to parse across documents. Python's `lxml` can run XSLT 1.0 scripts.

**XSLT** *(save as .xsl in same folder as source file, adjust 'replacethis' and 'srctxt' names)*

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml"/>
  <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

  <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- UPDATE <replacethis> TAG WITH <srctxt> FROM SOURCE -->
  <xsl:template match="replacethis">
    <xsl:copy-of select="document('test-source.htm')/html/body/srctxt"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Python**

```
import lxml.etree as et

# LOAD XML AND XSL SOURCES
doc = et.parse('test-target.htm')
xsl = et.parse('XSLTScript.xsl')

# TRANSFORM SOURCE
transform = et.XSLT(xsl)
result = transform(doc)

# OUTPUT TO SCREEN
print(result)    

# OUTPUT TO FILE
with open('test-target.htm', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(result)
```

**Output**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <srctxt>text to be added</srctxt>
    <p>irrelevant, just here for filler</p>
    <srctxt>text to be added</srctxt>
  </body>
</html>
```